# Dependency Injection in Angular 8

Tags: angular8

There have been several questions already posted with specific questions about dependency injection, such as when to use it and what frameworks are there for it. However,

What is dependency injection in Angular 8 and when/why should or shouldn't it be used?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is EVERYTHING in Angular :)

The hierarchical dependency injection system is parallels to the app's component tree and basically, allow us to build the whole applications injecting providers and communicating between components.

The documentation is quite complete and it's worth to study to know the details:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection